# How to add single quote to heredoc javascript?

Tags: javascript, heredoc

I have this heredoc code:

```
$col_formatter = <<<COLFORMATTER
function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    var tracking = rowObject[5];
    var Tes = tracking;

    return '<input type="button" value="Open" onclick="btnOpen('+tracking+')">';
}
COLFORMATTER;
```

but I can't seem to pass the tracking variable to the btnOpen js function.

For example, the value of tracking is "marsha". When I test it with Mozilla Firebug, it tells me that:

```
ReferenceError: Marsha is not defined
btnOpen(Marsha)
```

I'm thinking that I have to put a single quote when I pass it so that Marsha will be read as a string instead of variable. One thing I know how to put the quote is to add a backslash before it (\'):

```
return '<input type="button" value="Open" onclick="btnOpen(\''+tracking+'\')">';
```

But that doesn't work either. It says:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
...e=\"Open\" onclick=\"btnOpen(\\''+tracking+'\\')\">';}},{"name":"status"...
```

Why is that?

Comment: I think the version with the backslashes should work. Can you show how you're using `$col_formatter`?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) used to denote sequences with special meaning or conversely (in your case) imply [string-literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) on characters which would otherwise be interpreted as part of the language construct.

Escaping is common across many languages, you have to remember that you are constructing a javascript expression through a (looks like) *PHP* script - the character has meaning in both.

So... if you wish to print a literal `\` in your string you will have to escape it aswell:

```
... onclick="btnOpen(\\''+tracking+'\\')" ...
```